# SEQ custmisation in R

Tags: r

`seq(from = as.POSIXct("2017-12-31", tz = "GMT"), length.out = 12, by="month" )`

Output i get using this -:

`[1] "2017-12-31 GMT" "2018-01-31 GMT" "2018-03-03 GMT" "2018-03-31 GMT" "2018-05-01 GMT" "2018-05-31 GMT" "2018-07-01 GMT"
 [8] "2018-07-31 GMT" "2018-08-31 GMT" "2018-10-01 GMT" "2018-10-31 GMT" "2018-12-01 GMT"`

Expected output-:

`[1] "2017-12-31 GMT" "2018-01-31 GMT" "2018-02-29 GMT" "2018-03-31 GMT" "2018-04-30 GMT" "2018-05-31 GMT" "2018-06-30 GMT"
 [8] "2018-07-31 GMT" "2018-08-31 GMT" "2018-09-30 GMT" "2018-10-31 GMT" "2018-11-30 GMT"`

```
str<- "2014-01-01 17:00:00"
interval <- "hour"

seq(from = as.POSIXct(str, tz = "IST"), length.out = forecast_point + 1, by = interval )

str1 <- "2017-12-31"
interval1 <- "month"

seq(ceiling_date(as.Date(str1, tz = "GMT"), "month"),length.out = 12,   by = interval1)
```

those are working alternatively if you pass `str1` and `iterval1` in above syntax it gives wrong output

please suggest me how can i do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try `seq(from = as.Date("2018-01-01", tz = "GMT"), length.out = 12, by="month" )-1`. There is no 29th for Feb in 2018

Comment: In the second case, I see that. you defined `str1` and passed `str`

Comment: that was by mistake , please check it out

Answer (score 3):

One option is to get the sequence from the first date and then subtract 1 to get the last day of previous month.

```
seq(from =as.Date("2017-12-31", tz = "GMT") + 1 , 
        length.out = 12, by="month" )-1
#[1] "2017-12-31" "2018-01-31" "2018-02-28" "2018-03-31" "2018-04-30" "2018-05-31" "2018-06-30" "2018-07-31" "2018-08-31" "2018-09-30" "2018-10-31" "2018-11-30"
```

---

Also, if we are passing any dates, then can use `ceiling_date` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
seq(ceiling_date(as.Date("2017-12-05", tz = "GMT"), "month"),
        length.out = 12, by = "month") - 1
```

Comment: it works , i can't pass "2018-01-01" , i have to pass "2017-12-31" this , please suggest me with this input (because input varies over the time)

Comment: @jony If that is the case just add 1

Comment: @jony I updated the post.  It should work now.  Do you have value  "2017-12-24" as input

Comment: it varies , let me give you more detail here

Comment: @jony The. updated one  with `ceiling_date` should work for that too

Comment: if input ` "2014-01-01 17:00:00"` and by `hour ` it doesn't work , if `tz` change to `IST` then it work , same thing with `2017-12-31` this

Comment: @jony. Not clear what you expect there.  Could you please show your expected output.  I think your question was about `month`.  If we are going to extend it to many other things, I have a feeling that the scope of the question is changed